# Setting default text parameter to a PostgreSQL function causes "column doesn't exist" error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a function with two text parameters, second one should have a default value "en" (it is a localisation parameter).

```
CREATE FUNCTION nav.getpathtext_new(path text, locale text DEFAULT "en") RETURNS json AS
$BODY$DECLARE
-- function code here ...
RETURN array_to_json(_toJson);

END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
```

And I'm getting error:

> ERROR: column "en" does not exist
>
> LINE 1: ...getpathtext_new(path text, locale text DEFAULT "en") RETU..
>
> ```
>                             ^
> ```

PostgreSQL version is 9.4.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try single qoutes   `DEFAULT 'en'`

Comment: Oh, silly mistake. Thanks! Could you please post this suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use single quotes `'` to specify text values so

`CREATE FUNCTION nav.getpathtext_new(path text, locale text DEFAULT "en") RETURNS json AS`

becomes

`CREATE FUNCTION nav.getpathtext_new(path text, locale text DEFAULT 'en') RETURNS json AS`